Expo background timer
I'm currently working on a project using Expo and I need to implement a background timer functionality. I've looked into Expo Background Fetch as it seems to be the recommended solution for this within the Expo ecosystem. However, despite following the example provided in the documentation, I haven't been able to get it to work.
I've followed the steps outlined in the documentation, but still, the background fetch doesn't seem to trigger consistently or at all.

Has anyone successfully implemented a background timer using Expo Background Fetch?
If so, could you please share your implementation or any insights into what might be going wrong with mine?
Alternatively, are there any other libraries or approaches within the Expo ecosystem that you would recommend for implementing a background timer?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I've looked into Expo Background Fetch as it seems to be the recommended solution for this within the Expo ecosystem. However, despite following the example provided in the documentation, I haven't been able to get it to work.
